# Continuous labels problem of the mini pages in the two figures

Tags: captions, minipage

Problem: The mini pages is used in two figures. But the mini pages labels are continuous in the two figures.

How to make the mini pages labeled (3a) and (3b), not (3c) and (3d) in figure 3?

[image: fig.2 and fig.3 mini page label is continuous]

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
\centering\includegraphics[width=2cm]{logo2}% This is a *.eps file
\subcaption{A subfigure}\label{fig:2a}
\end{minipage}\\
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
\centering\includegraphics[width=2cm]{logo2}% This is an *.eps file
\subcaption{Another subfigure}\label{fig:2b}
\end{minipage}
\caption{A figure}\label{fig:2b}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
\centering\includegraphics[width=2cm]{logo2}% This is a *.eps file
\subcaption{A subfigure}\label{fig:2a}
\end{minipage}\\
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
\centering\includegraphics[width=2cm]{logo2}% This is an *.eps file
\subcaption{Another subfigure}\label{fig:2b}
\end{minipage}
\caption{A figure}\label{fig:2b}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: We need a complete document to see why this is.

Comment: @PietvanOostrum asked for an MWE of your problem.  I tried you given code, and it works.  You must have defined the subcaption counter, as my subcaptions are only labeled a) and b), while yours do use the figure number.

Comment: I am so sorry my late reply and I did not submit a complete document, since I use a template. Thank you for your suggestion for the subcaption counter defined @Jan

Comment: I use `\setcounter{subfigure}{0}` to reset the subfigure counter. Thx.

Comment: @taiping.z, did my answer solved your problem?  If so, you could marked it as solved :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use something like this in your preamble `\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\thefigure\alph{subfigure}}`

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\thefigure\alph{subfigure}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
\centering\includegraphics[width=2cm]{logo}% This is a *.eps file
\subcaption{A subfigure}\label{fig:2a}
\end{minipage}\\
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
\centering\includegraphics[width=2cm]{logo}% This is an *.eps file
\subcaption{Another subfigure}\label{fig:2b}
\end{minipage}
\caption{A figure}\label{fig:2b}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
\centering\includegraphics[width=2cm]{logo}% This is a *.eps file
\subcaption{A subfigure}\label{fig:2a}
\end{minipage}\\
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
\centering\includegraphics[width=2cm]{logo}% This is an *.eps file
\subcaption{Another subfigure}\label{fig:2b}
\end{minipage}
\caption{A figure}\label{fig:2b}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: definition `\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\thefigure\alph{subfigure})}`  is surplus and double parenthesis ...

Comment: the same result you obtain also if you delete `\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\thefigure\alph{subfigure})` :) that was point pf all my comments. With OP code, which shi/he show, is OK. But we don't see its preamble ...

Comment: @zarko Sorry, in that case, the label on the subfigure is only (a), (b) and so on.  Requested of the original poster was (3a) and so on.  At least, my MWE does not show the requested results, if your don't set the `\subfigure...`

Comment: ah, i miss read question ...